# JS error with saving admin side form data

Tags: grid, adminform, magento2.1.6

In the custom module with grid i am getting error as following :

```
TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined
```

in magento 2 admin form in tab

It was working  perfectly without tab and saving form data in database. But, after this i have added form in tab and m not able to save data. When i am saving or save and continue it's giving error as above.

I am using magento 2.1.6 and also run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy but not working.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you are using the following code in your **_prepareForm()** function

```
$form->setUseContainer(true);
```

If so, try commenting this code and re-check.